# Stretched Picture with google Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have tested the CSS in Firefox and it renders as I would expect.
But in Safari & Chrome, the pictures are stretched.

**CSS:**

[image]

**Chrome:**

[image]

**FIREFOX:**

[image]

Comment: Mention the css in the question itself not as the url

Comment: Without a working example to test, it's difficult to tell you what to do, but have you tried also adding this to the css code: display: -webkit-flex; ? If that doesn't work, try display: inline-flex; - otherwise you'll have to provide a working example..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Cedric Marcelus, please always provide some code along with your question. It will help others and help us in helping you. If you can link the website that would be perfect, try to determine what is causing the problem by narrowing it down and making a minimal working example. Please have a go at reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)